# What is a person that leaves a piece of advice called?

Tags: single-word-requests

Piece of advice / tips.

E.g. "Don't eat yellow snow" or "There's this great restaurant down at [location]"

Is there a word for someone leaving advice like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is '[pundit](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pundit?s=t)'

> **Pundit** : noun
>
> 1 - a learned person, expert, or authority.
>
> 2 - a person who makes comments or judgments, especially in an authoritative manner; critic or commentator.
>
> www.dictionary.com